# Flask Jinja code inside two blocks with <b> HTML code

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Can someone please explain these lines of code? I know we are setting `hl` to correct if its min is lower than highlited min, but I don't understand why we finish the `if` block after opening bolding HTML code. Shouldn't I put `endif` after all of the bolding code?

```
 {% set hl = weather[month]['max'] >= highlight['max'] %}
        {% if hl %}<b>{% endif %}
        {{ weather[month]['max'] }}
        {% if hl %}</b>{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is unclear? If you removed the first `endif` and second `if hl` then the *whole block* would be conditional, as opposed to whether or not it's bold. In fact, why not make that change and see what happens? Experimenting is a good way to learn!

Answer (score 2):

The `if` appears twice because **both the starting and ending bold tags are conditional** - the text appears either way, it's only whether or not it's bold that varies with the value of `highlight['max']`. The alternative to the code you've shown is:

```html
{% if weather[month]['max'] >= highlight['max'] %}
    <b>{{ weather[month]['max'] }}</b>
{% else %}
    {{ weather[month]['max'] }}
{% endif %}
```

which is perhaps clearer for the novice reader, but means duplication of the `{{ weather[month]['max'] }}` part.

Answer (score 1):

The first if is to print the opening tag, the second is to place the closing tag 
and the value is always printed.

Conclusion only if this if is true, the value will be bold, else the value won't be bold.

```
{% set hl = weather[month]['max'] >= highlight['max'] %}
        {% if hl %} // <= Opening tag if the condition is true
               <b>
        {% endif %}

           {{ weather[month]['max'] }} //  <= Value 

        {% if hl %} // <= Closing tag if the condition is true
               </b>
        {% endif %}
```

**Explanation:**
If the temperature is higher that the max temperature defined in highlight['max'] , then mark it with bold.

Comment: sorry I'm still confused shouldn't the value be put before the first end if?

Comment: you want to generate tag that looks like this
<b>VALUE</b> for high temperature and 
      VALUE 
for Regular, This why it's placed inside the 2 if's

Comment: yeah I get that but why do we finish if h1 before </b> shouldn't the value be bolded then finish if statement. isn't it like if h1 is true then bold, and after bolded finish if statement?

Comment: There are 2 different if in order to avoid printing the value 2 times, please direct me what is miss confuse you...

Comment: ok first of all thanks for helping me out, I don't understand how the effect of <b> is still alive after if is ended. like it should only be alived when h1 is true right?after if is finished h1 doesn't have to be true. why do we put two if statement between <b>

Comment: <b> tag have an opening and a close tag, so if you want to add it you need to add it before and after the value this why you have 2 if's
"1 if" for before "2 if" for after

Comment: Cause you want to output the closing task